# How to import .ts into another .ts file in Angular 5 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some utils methods inside a utils.ts file which need to be reused by several
components.
I'm not sure whether it possible and if yes where to put the import and what is
the syntax if any.
I've tried the index.html file:

```
<script src="assets/ts/utils.js?v=1.2"></script>
```

And getting error:

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/ts/utils.js?v=1.2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Should I import to each component separately and if yes, what is the syntax ?
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't import your js, you must import your ts in the component and webpack will do the trick

Comment: `I have some utils methods inside a utils.ts`, but you import a JS file. What's the actual case there ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that what you are trying to import is a .js, not a ts.A 404 error is that you are not finding the file that you indicate in the specified path.

I recommend that you check the path and the name of the file so that they are exactly the same. Can you also try to remove `? V = 1.2`.

If you really want to add a `.ts` file to your project, the import should be done through `app.component.ts` and not with an import in the `Index.html`

Comment: I added import into the app.component.ts  import '../assets/ts/utils.ts'; I'm getting no error from the import. But I'm getting error that the method inside the ts file is RROR ReferenceError: digitGrouping is not defined

Comment: Can you show me how you are importing the library to the component, how the instances and how do you call it? The error may be that the instance you make in the component is incorrect, and therefore the object you are creating to call your library is undefined

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by importing in each component I need trhe ts util, this is the import: import { Utils } from '../../../assets/ts/utils'; I prefer to do it in one place but there is no good option I'm ok with this approach.